# I can't open minecraft 1.8.3 problem in Java?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I try to open Minecraft the program stops and takes me back to the app launcher, the full problem is listed below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/Platform
    at oshi.SystemInfo.<init>(SystemInfo.java:32)
    at h.<clinit>(SourceFile:16)
    at avf.<clinit>(SourceFile:147)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:41)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Platform
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 4 more
```

I have tried reinstalling Java and Minecraft.

Comment: The error message looks like it is cut off (`... 4 more`), could you post the full log? Have you tried upgrading to the lastest Minecraft version? Has this problem always occured? Do you have any mods?

Comment: Nope, it does not look like it's been cut off @colorfusion. That is default java behaviour, it does not show the internal stacks that are meaningless to all but people working on the java VM source code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a not unheard of problem where Minecraft is incapable of downloading [the Java Native Access library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access), mostly because it can't save the files to the location it wants to save them.

Running it as administrator should fix the problem.

Source: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2362518-what-was-the-cause-and-the-solution-to-this